# Why does the github API use token instead of Bearer as their Authorization type

Tags: github, oauth-2.0

Why does the github API use `token` instead of `Bearer` as the Authorization type?

See [github.js](https://github.com/michael/github/blob/2c7ab31be7a12187a6aa95c4498139ae4c701508/github.js) line 61

Answer (score 1):

I checked Github OAuth Guide, and found the [response to successful authorization request](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#response) takes the following form:
`access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a&scope=user%2Cgist&token_type=bearer`, where token_type is `bearer`.

But in [Use the access token to access the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-api), the request approach is to include it in the Authorization header:
`Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN`

As [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7.1) says:

> Each access token type definition specifies the additional attributes
> (if any) sent to the client together with the "access_token" response
> parameter.  **It also defines the HTTP authentication method** used to
> include the access token when making a protected resource request.

And Bearer is the [standard Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1).
I haven't found any other OAuth implementation using `token` as a scheme.

So it's quite interesting, I hope some Github guys can give their thinking about this.